# Как реализовать переключение на программу?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне надо сделать брут, и чтобы когда его запускал она сразу переключалась на эту программу.

Это можно сделать через название процесса?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\text.txt");

        int amount = 0;
        while (amount < 10)
        {

            string Number;
            sw.WriteLine("Номер: " + (amount + 1));
            amount++;

        }

        sw.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Что вы подразумеваете под словом "брут"?  "...чтобы когда его запускал она сразу переключалась на эту программу." - "она" - это кто? Брут? Ну, так ведь это "он".

Comment: Надо чтобы программа по нажатию кнопки переключалась на окно (например: skype), вводила пароль длинной 4 символа через запятую, также после каждой запятой нажимала кнопку Alt.

Comment: Горе хацкер, советую вам для начала подучить язык, подучить как работают сервисы, как работают такие программы и уже затем думать, стоит вам на этот скользкий путь вставать или нет. Дам подсказку - не обязательно иметь вообще установленный "скайп", достаточно отправить правильный запрос на правильный адрес!

Comment: А какое отношение опубликованный код имеет к брутфорсу паролей? | И вообще: Караул! Милиция! У меня скайп угнали!

Answer (score 1):

Посылает текст textToSend на апликуху с ЗАГОЛОВКОМ процесса  processTitle.
Не важно оно консольное или WinForm.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public void SendTextToProcess(string processTitle, string textToSend)
{
    IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
    for (int i = 0; (i < 10) && (zero == IntPtr.Zero); i++)//Пытается найти окно
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        zero = FindWindow(null, processTitle);
    }
    if (zero != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(zero);//делает окно активным (например консоли)
        SendKeys.SendWait(textToSend);//посылает нужные нажатия клавиш В ФОРМУ, но при этом банально не выбирает поле в которое нужно вводить
        SendKeys.Flush();
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
SendTextToProcess("Untitled - Notepad", "hello World{ENTER}Tab{TAB}{TAB}test{TAB}{TAB}finished{ENTER}");
```

Напечатает в открытом пустом блокноте:

```
hello World
Tab     test        finished
```